# Proofing that the Lucas numbers come closer to the Phi rounded numbers then the Fibonacci numbers.

Tags: fibonacci-numbers, golden-ratio, lucas-numbers

Morning everyone,

Bit of background, I'm a mid level programmer with very limited mathematics skills. As part of an assessment for a new role I've been asked to complete a technical task which mirrors the title of this question.

The programming side is fine yet it is the mathematics side of things that have confused me. We have been given a sample output to replicate(see below).

**Fibonacci:** 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377, 610

**Lucas:** 2, 1, 3, 4, 7, 11, 18, 29, 47, 76, 123, 199, 322, 521, 843

**Phi Rounded:** 2, 2, 3, 4, 7, 11, 18, 29, 47, 76, 123, 199, 322, 521, 843

Now where I come unstuck, I understand how Fibonacci and Lucas work and the sequence begins but it is the rounded Phi sequence that confuses me. From 3 onwards it seems to generate the next number like the previous 2. It is the beginning of 2,2 that confuses me. Obviously Phi rounded is 2 so how is the second 2 generated in this sequence? Is there a rule that I am missing?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

We have been told to assume Phi is 1.618.

Comment: **To proof** something in English means to make something (like a boat) water-proof. **To prove** something is what you want.

Comment: Once one has a proof, it is not a bad idea to proof it just to be sure, of course!

Comment: How is the sequence named **Phi Rounded** generated?

Comment: "Closer" usually implies some kind of metric ("distance function", to put it simply). For infinite sequences, to my knowledge, there is no canonical ("natural", "classical") metric and there is a metric $d$ so that $d(F,\phi) < d(L,\phi)$.

Comment: Seems that the Lucas Number are not only close to the phi-rounded numbers, but identical (with a single exception). Probably, it can be shown by induction that this is actually the case.

Comment: If, however, the approximation $1.618$ is used instead of $\phi$, the coincidence will vanish at some point.

Comment: My English is nearly as poor as my Mathematics!

Comment: @gammatester I'm unsure as to how this sequence is generated, I have only been given the the expected output with no explanation as to how to why it is like so. My understanding was the golden ration is 1 constant, as a total novice I don't see how a sequence is generated similar to the Lucas and Fibonacci sequence. Would it be possible there is something incorrect in the examiners logic?